# Image Won't Show - CSS

Tags: css, image, html, hidden

I am having a weird issue with a CSS bug for mobile / desktop devices.

On mobile, an image for one of my classes won't show up, but the content area for it will.

On desktop, an image for one of my classes will show up, including the content area for it.

This is how I am creating my image:

```
<div class="image">
<img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

This is what I am doing in my mobile.css file:

```
.image {

width: 471px;
height: 513px;
float: left;
}
```

In another one of my files (for iPhone) I am not showing the image so I am doing this:

```
.image {
   display: none;
}
```

Could that be causing my issue?

Comment: try to add `display:block !important` in your first css

Comment: I did and then the image shows up completely different than it would on desktop @softsdev

Comment: But the conflict between the two classes but same class name could be what is making it dissapear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .image {
    display : none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having recently having this problem myself, it was due to the image file size being too large (in file size, not dimension). Try and make the file type smaller and then it will eventually load. Try a [site like this](http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx) to help you.

Comment: it's ironic, because I just realized that :)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the `display: none;` rule is applied in the other situations, yes. Remove this rule, then try again. Whenever something strange happens, I remove blocks of code, part by part, to see what is causing the problem. All editors have undo, so I remove a block, test, and undo, remove the next block etc.